# Capturing Responses from iCal/ics file

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I am generating ics/iCal files for events in a Web app and emailing them to users to add to their calendars. This part works great

I would like to require a response in the ics files and then capture their responses.  I was under the impression I can specify a URL to my Web app in the ics file. Then I can parse the email and attendee status from the response format.

Is something like this possible? I can't find any ics documentation to handle something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. It's possible to specify in an iCalendar object that a user should respond, (by using the relevant parameters in the `ATTENDEE` property), but the result will be sent back as an e-mail response.

*unless* the receiving user runs a caldav server with scheduling support.

Comment: Thank you Evert. If you have a minute, can you clarify if the email response contains the necessary fields to parse, such as email recipient and accept/deny response?

Comment: There is a boolean property on Attendee 'RSVP'.  If this is sent to true the user will be prompted to send an email response.

Comment: @I_Khanage this is not what OP asked though.

Comment: @Evert I may have misunderstood but I thought you were saying that you can get a user to respond by setting 'relevant parameters' on Attendee and then he was asking which parameters.

I did this by setting RSVP to true but if you have had a different experience then please put it down.  It may well help someone :)